# How to take out a word from a list which is separated by ":"?

Tags: python, split

I am currently creating a program which automatically creates accounts on a Website and I want to verify them by SMS. I am using Python 3 and Selenium.

First the program to sends a request to the site.

```
getNumber = requests.get('https://sms-service-online.com/stubs/handler_api?api_key=APIkey&action=getNumber&service=ew&operator=any&country=0&lang=en')
```

Then I am getting a pure HTML text as response.

```
ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813
```

**Here comes the problem:**

The HTML text means `ACCESSNUMBER:ID:PHONE_NUMBER`. I want to separate the ID and the Access number.

So that I could print them easily out with for example this code:

```
print(number)
print(id)
```

In addition I want to remove the 7 in the beginning from the number, the number changes but the 7 in the beginning never does because its the country code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve the result:

### Using `split()`

To print the *ID* separately:

```
# text = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813"
print(text.split(":")[1]) #Console Output: 57554715
```

To print the *Access number* separately:

```
# text = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813"
print(text.split(":")[2]) #Console Output: 79050762813
```

To get rid of the first number i.e. `7` from the *Access number*:

```
# text = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813"
print(text.split(":")[2][1:]) #Console Output: 9050762813
```

---

### Using `re`

To print the *ID* separately:

```
import re

# text = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813"
print(re.split('[:]', text)[1]) #Console Output: 57554715
```

To print the *Access number* separately:

```
import re

# text = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813"
print(re.split('[:]', text)[2]) #Console Output: 79050762813
```

To get rid of the first number i.e. `7` from the *Access number*:

```
import re

# text = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813"
print(re.split('[:]', text)[2][1:]) #Console Output: 9050762813
```

Comment: A regular expression for **one** character? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [split](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) function:

```py
content = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813"

access_number, id_number, phone_number = content.split(":")

print(id_number)
print(phone_number)

# output
# >>> '57554715'
# >>> '79050762813'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use

```
number, id, phone = "ACCESS_NUMBER:57554715:79050762813".split(":")

if phone.startswith("7"):
    phone = phone[1:]
```

Comment: If I type | number, id, phone = getNumber.split(":") | I am getting this error message  | AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'split' |

Answer (score 0):

```
getNumber = getNumber.split(":")
number = getNumber[1]
id = getNumber[2]
```

to get rid of the first digit:

```
id = getNumber[2][1:]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error msg: AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Try str(response).split(":")

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need to be able to do, then could you store the Access text/number in a string, which is an array of characters, then choose the characters you need?

Example:

```
a = "Hello, World!"
print(a[1])
```

Would print out

```
e
```

You can also return a range of characters:

```
b = "Hello, World!"
print(b[2:5])
```

Would print out:

```
llo
```